# How to get the CGContext for a NavigationPage control in a Xamarin Forms Renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm attempting to create a fullscreen overlay for my app.  To do this, I need to override the renderer for `NavigationPage`, because no other item can be positioned over the navigation bar, even with absolute positioning.

I have a custom renderer where I'm attempting to draw over navigation bar like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Controls
{
    public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
            using CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, context is always `null`.  In examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137139) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4bbd7ebe-44ec-4514-8a0d-f5c28598c974/core-graphics-calls-within-a-xamarin-forms-ios-custom-renderer?forum=xamarinforms) they say you need to call `UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext()` from within the overridden `Draw()` function, but no such function exists within `NavigationRenderer`.

On Android it can be done by overriding `NavigationPageRenderer.DispatchDraw()`, but that does not exist on the iOS `NavigationRenderer`.  **How do I draw on this control in iOS?**

Comment: To create a fullscreen overlay , did you try to use [Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup) ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT That does not meet my needs, I'm not looking for a popup. But perhaps I can see how they implement the background overlay.

Comment: Do you want to add a translucent  background overlay over the whole screen ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT: Yes. The ultimate goal is to have a translucent overlay with a fully-transparent "hole" highlighting one part of the screen. I'm doing this with a custom page renderer because that is the _only_ method that works with a navigation bar in Android. But if the answer to my question is "it can't be done in iOS", I'll need to use a completely different method for each OS (which is an entirely different question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Dependency service and add a translucent background overlay on the root window .

##### Sample code

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void present();
}

IMyInterface service = DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>();
service.present();
```

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IMyInterface))]
namespace ColeForms.iOS
{
    public class MyInterface : IMyInterface
    {

        UIView overlay;
        public MyInterface()
        {
            overlay = new UIView();

            //full screen
            overlay.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;

            //translucent background 
            overlay.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(0.5f,0.5f);

            //add the tap gesture to dismiss overlap
            overlay.AddGestureRecognizer(new UITapGestureRecognizer(()=> {
                overlay.RemoveFromSuperview();
            }));
        }


        public void present()
        {
          UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Add(overlay);
        }
    }
}
```

##### Screen shot

[image]

Comment: This mostly worked. Instead of a generic `UIView`, I wrote a custom class which inherits `UIView` and overrides the `Draw()` function.  In there, I can `UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext()` and draw whatever I want. I also, for whatever dumb reason, had to set `this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;` in the UIView constructor, or else the entire control would always be black.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final solution I came up with, based on ColeX's answer above

MyCustomOverlay.cs

```
namespace MyApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// There's no way to "Draw" over a page in iOS, so we create a custom control that takes up the entire page and draw on that instead
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class MyCustomOverlay : UIView
    {
        public MyCustomOverlay()
        {
            this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear; // This is *required* or else the entire control is black. lol?
            AddGestureRecognizer(new UITapGestureRecognizer(RemoveFromSuperview)); // Close overlay when clicked
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();
            this.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        }

        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);
            using CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            // Include your draw code here
        }
    }
}
```

MyNavigationPageRenderer.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(MyNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        private UIView RootView => UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View;

        public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
            if (!RootView.Subviews.Any(o => o is MyCustomOverlay))
            {
                RootView.Add(new MyCustomOverlay());
            }
        }
    }
}
```